# Paint coming back off wall using brush

Tags: painting

I have decided to decorate the bedroom and have now gotten around to do the painting. I initially gave all four walls one coat of a light grey soft sheen paint which covered nicely. I then gave 3 walls a second coat of the same paint which covered all the odd patches nicely.

I figured I would use a darker color paint for the feature wall so I got a darker grey, still soft sheen but is a different brand. The wall just doesn't want to take at all. I am trying to cut in with a brush but unless I lather it on thick, the paint just comes back off when I try to brush it out.

Has this got anything to do with the different brands of paint or its being soft sheen? I have tried multiple brushes but it just seems to keep pulling away and I end up with patches. I used a 12-inch medium pile roller to do the main body of the wall which works great, but I can't go around the edges with a brush. Any idea why?

Comment: How much sheen are we talking? Eggshell? Semi-gloss? High-gloss?

Comment: Either the original surface was greasy or something is fundamentally incompatible about the paints. Daniel, you need to provide more detail. We're stumbling in the dark here. What _type_ of paint (or brand name) are we talking about? What did you paint over?

Comment: Since the failure is happening *between* different paints, please, name the paint brand, type (each brand has several) and gloss level for each of the two paints, and state how long you waited between each coat.  Photos of the cans would help, or even UPCs. [edit] your post to add info.

Comment: Hi sorry, i know this is slightly too late but i managed to solve it by just frog taping all the way round and using a different large roller into the edges. I initially used valspars paint for the first coat and then johnstons for the second. Both were labeled as 'soft sheen'.